# Hybrid application using Cordova and Ionic framework and writing CSS for Mobile, Tablet and Desktop

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid

I am trying to build an hybrid app using Cordova and Ionic framework. In the progress I was thinking will the same CSS work for Mobile, Tablet and Desktop. I am more concerned using the Vh and Vw (relative units based on view-port height and width) in css for desktop and based on the different monitor resolution it will increase the font size, icon and image size.

So Is it the best the way to code it. Or should I create separate css file for desktop to handle different resolutions. What is the best approach to create a hybrid app which will work in mobile, tablet and desktop with one code base.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: If you are writing your custom css to make it responsive then you can use media queries or else you can give with some responsive framework like Bootstrap that will help you build apps for any size of device

Comment: But I am building an app using cordova and ionic. And it has pros with angular js support

Answer (score 0):

Ionic itself provide the responsive grid by which you can align your content.

You can check out here for further info. http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#grid

Comment: Right ionic provides responsive grid, but it uses vh and vw so that based on the mobile device viewport the size of the text and icon resizes. But what about desktop, is it ok to use vh and vw? If I use vh and vw then the page will resize based on the monitors resolution. So is it best way to do it?

Comment: I do not think ionic app will run on the desktop.Ionic is purely for mobile app development.  Ionic is specifically for mobile and tablet app. So no need to think about the resolution problem as ionic already handles this for you. Go ahead and use ionic grid and see the result live on the desktop using ionic lab.

Answer (score 0):

It comes down to what version you are using currently in the ionic framework, to create the best UX.

**Ionic 1**

Ionic 1 is focused on building native/hybrid mobile apps rather than mobile websites. Some of the limitations you would likely run into over time is UI/UX and browser support. It honestly depends on what you are more focused on.

If a native/hybrid app is the main approach then yes, using ionic is fine (but the website may not be the best UI/UX). If you are more focused on the web app and not the native/hybrid app then I would not suggest using ionic.

[Documentation for Ionic 1](http://ionicframework.com/docs/)

**Ionic 2**

Ionic 2 is focused on building both native/hybrid apps though Cordova, as well as adding the ability for Progressive Web Apps and Electron, as mentioned [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/overview/#browser-support). If you take this approach and want the best of both worlds then there are plenty of tools to make it happen.

Note that Ionic 2 leverages Angular 2, the projects are structured differently from Ionic v1 to v2 (in a more intuitive way). I suggest looking of the documentation for both, what your best interests are for the end user and make a decision based on that.

[Documentation for Ionic 2](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/)

Comment: I did go through the documentation but I am little confused whether I should go with Cordova + ionic wth one code base for mobile, tablet and desktop. Is there any other tool you can suggest me as an alternative.